# Extract tuple parts to create another two tuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples

I have this dataset:

```
       duplicates              id   userid  timestamp_date
0   (007, us1, us2, 6, 7, 1)    b   us1      1
1   (001, us1, us2, 1, 9, 8)    b   us2      7 
2   (009, us1, us2, 1, 28, 27)  b   us1      8
3   (007, us1, us2, 6, 7, 1)    c   us2      9
4   (009, us2, us1, 1, 29, 28)  c   us4     10.    



d = pd.DataFrame({'duplicates':      [("007", "us1", "us2", 6, 7, 1),  ("001", "us1", "us2", 1, 9, 8), ("009", "us1", "us2", 1, 28, 27), ("007", "us1", "us2", 6, 7, 1), ("009", "us2", "us1", 1, 29, 28)], 
     'id': ["b",   "b",   "b", 'c', "c"], 
     'userid':         ["us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4"],
     "timestamp_date": [1,    7,      8,     9,  10]})
```

And I want to extract the tuples is the following way:
tuple(a, b, c, d, e, f) -> tuple(a, b, null, e) and tuple (a, c, d, f).

So the result should be:

```
    duplicates            id
0   (007, us1, null, 7)    b
1   (007, us2, 6, 1)       b
2   (001, us1, null, 9)    b
3   (001, us2, 1, 8)       b
4   (009, us1, null, 28).  b
5   (009, us2, 1, 27)      b
6   (007, us1, null, 7)    c
7   (007, us2, 6, 1)       c
8   (009, us2, null, 29).  c
9   (009, us1, 1, 28)      c

e = pd.DataFrame({'duplicates':      [("007", "us1", null, 7),  ("007", "us2", 6, 1), 
                                      ("001", "us1", null, 9), ("001", "us2", 1, 8),
                                      ("009", "us1", null, 28), ("009", "us2", 1, 27),
                                       ("007", "us1", null, 7),  ("007", "us2", 6, 1),
                                       ("009", "us2", null, 29), ("009", "us1", 1, 28)], 
     'id': ["b",   "b",   "b", "b",   "b",   "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]})
```

I don't like to put questions without code but I really have no idea where I should start and I couldn't find on other questions. I tried to use zip with apply(), but I don't think is this way because I didn't even could make the runtime errors stop appearing.

Comment: Are the "tuples" just strings like in your example or real tuples?

Comment: oh, no, they are real tuples! I changed now. As I do a lot of operations in my dataset for arriving on that I didn't want to pollute the question with lots of operations and then I've just typed the tuples down and made this mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.apply()` to split the tuple to list of two tuples and then `.explode()`:

```
d = (d.assign(duplicates=d['duplicates'].apply(lambda x: [(x[0], x[1], None, x[4]), (x[0], x[2], x[3], x[5])]))
      .explode('duplicates')
      .drop(columns=['userid', 'timestamp_date']))

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
             duplicates id
0   (007, us1, None, 7)  b
0      (007, us2, 6, 1)  b
1   (001, us1, None, 9)  b
1      (001, us2, 1, 8)  b
2  (009, us1, None, 28)  b
2     (009, us2, 1, 27)  b
3   (007, us1, None, 7)  c
3      (007, us2, 6, 1)  c
4  (009, us2, None, 29)  c
4     (009, us1, 1, 28)  c
```